# how do I configure trn4 for multiple news servers?

Tags: command-line, man, hostname, domain, usenet

I'm running Leafnode as an easy-to-use NNTP server and am considering switching from pan as news reader to trn4.  To [configure trn4](https://askubuntu.com/a/866750/45156) I set it to, effectively, `localhost`.  Specifically, the FQDN which leafnode uses, which is also the hostname for the system.  Presumably trn4 doesn't use DNS to try and resolve the FQDN but realizes that this is `localhost` in this case.  That's working fine.

How can I add additional news servers?  Specifically, `news.gmane.org` so that I have the most recent postings, which Leafnode might not have.  Is the trn4 news host configuration file even `/etc/news/server`?  The man page was too long.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `/etc/news/server` can only hold a single server name, which is used by trn4 to configure a default source.

You can enable multiple news sources by creating a `~/.trn/access` file.  The documentation is, er, not what it might be, but there are some examples that come with the source distribution and may be packaged with your binary distribution.  I think [HelpFiles/sample/access](http://trn.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/trn/trn4/HelpFiles/samples/access?revision=1.1) is probably the most useful one to start from.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple news servers should be specified in ~/.trn/access

trn doesn't support ssl natively so be aware any usernames and passwords are sent in cleartext. You may wish to consider using stunnel or similar provide a SSL connection to your news servers.

```
# trn4 ~/.trn/access
# access file for multiple news servers.
# trn4 does not support SSL natively so stunnel
# running on localhost is used to provide ssl.
# CHMOD this to 0600 as it contains your
# CLEARTEXT usernames and passwords.
#
# You must ensure 
# Use Newsrc selector option is set to yes
#
[eternal-september]
# news eternal-september.org
# connect via local stunnel
# client to port 563
NNTP Server = 127.0.0.3;10563
Group Desc Refresh = 7 days
Auth User = esuser 
Auth Password = espassword
# E-S needs Force Auth
# to get full groups list.
Force Auth = yes
[gmane]
# gmane using default
# connection port 119
NNTP Server = news.gmane.org
Group Desc Refresh = 7 days
[newsindividual]
# news.individual.net
# connect via local
# stunnel client to port 563
NNTP Server = 127.0.0.4;10564
Auth User = ninuser
Auth Password = ninpassword
Group Desc Refresh = 7 days
[mixmin]
# news.mixmin.net
# doesn't require authentication.
# Another ssl connection via stunnel.
NNTP Server = 127.0.0.5;10565
Group Desc Refresh = 7 days
#
[Group 1]
ID = eternal-september
Newsrc = ~/.trn/newsrc.es
#
[Group 2]
ID = gmane
Newsrc = ~/.trn/newsrc.gmane
#
[Group 3]
ID = newsindividual
Newsrc = ~/.trn/newsrc.nin
#
[Group 4]
ID = mixmin
Newsrc = ~/.trn/newsrc.mixmin
#
```

I've included Gmane and some common news services in the file.